# How to get the particular userinfo in DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, dotnetnuke

Hi I'm using C# in developing my module in DNN and I have retrieved the users using this :

```
public ArrayList bindingListHere(string txtSearchUser){
    string getUsers = txtSearchUser;
    int totalrecords = 10;
    Users= UserController.GetUsersByUserName(PortalId, getUsers + "%", 0, 10, ref totalrecords, true, IsSuperUser);
    return Users;
}
```

And I bind it here:

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //calling the method from the lib that will search user of the portal
    DownloadCtrLib dctrl = new DownloadCtrLib ();
    dctrl.bindingListHere (txtSearchUser.Text);
    gvUser.DataSource = dctrl.bindingListHere (txtSearchUser.Text);
    gvUser.DataBind();
}
```

And it is working fine. It shows all the information regarding the user of the portal such as:

```
Email 
Firstname 
Lastname 
portalID
```

etc...

And that I dont want. Because I only need the UserID, Username and the DisplayName of the user. How can I do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a new simple class to your code that has only the fields you need.

```
public class UserBindings
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Then make a slight change to your binding method:

```
public List<UserBindings> bindingListHere(string txtSearchUser)
{
    string getUsers = txtSearchUser;
    int totalrecords = 10;
    ArrayList Users = UserController.GetUsersByUserName(PortalId, getUsers + "%", 0, 10, ref totalrecords, true, IsSuperUser);
    return Users.Cast<UserInfo>().Select(u => new UserBindings { UserID = u.UserID, Username = u.Username, DisplayName = u.DisplayName }).ToList();
}
```

I had to cast the Arraylist and use Linq to map the UserInfo to the UserBinding object. Now this method will return a list of UserBinding which is a much smaller collection than the previous ArrayList of UserInfo objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define the columns/properties in the GridView that you want to display if you simply want to limit what is being displayed. It sounds like you are letting it provide all the columns for all the properties.

Comment: How can I define that in gridview sir?